# The meaning of this sentence, especially, dafür

Tags: word-usage, preposition, german-to-english

The sentence:

> Es waren kaum Leute auf der Straße, dafür rasten die Autos ganz nah an uns vorbei.

DeepL translates it as:

> There were hardly any people on the street, but the cars sped past us very close.

Google, too, has about the same translation. But I haven't ever seen dafür used as an alternative to 'but'.

Comment: Please insert and quote text as text and not as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in the sentence 'stattdessen' instead of 'dafür'.
In this sentence 'dafür' is colloquial used as 'but'.

See meaning 4b in the [Duden article for 'dafür'.](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dafuer)

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. As I'm myself not that strong in language rules - do you have any (linkable internet) source for further reading? Because it sounds like two things - yet my understanding says: *dafür* is used as *but (aber)* - and *stattdessen* is an alternative to *but (aber)*. so *dafür* is used as *stattdessen*. In the meaning of *but (aber)*. Right?

Comment: Source -> [Duden](http://https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dafuer) In this sentence 'dafür' has the meaning of instead of. You can say following sentence: Ich komme heute nicht, dafür aber morgen. (colloquial)

Comment: @Erazor I've added the reference to the answer for you. Note that you can also expand your answer yourself using the edit button if you want to improve it further.

Comment: Wäre "deswegen" nicht das bessere Ersatzwort  in diesem Fall?